# How do I define a knockout binding handler in typescript?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I normally add custom [**knockout**](http://knockoutjs.com) [**binding handlers**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) in JavaScript via

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingHandler = {...}
```

but now I have to add them in [**TypeScript**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) via

```
ko.bindingHandlers["myBindingHandler"] = {...}
```

otherwise I get this error because I'm using [**typescript.d.ts**](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/knockout.d.ts):

> The property 'myBindingHandler' does not exist on value of type 'KnockoutBindingHandlers'

I don't like the `["property"]` approach because then I can't reference it or get intellisense on it later.

So, how can I add my custom binding handler to knockout while using [**definitelyTyped's knockout definition**](http://nuget.org/packages/knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/), while also being able to reference my definition via intellisense, etc?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Defining a custom binding handler

Its actually pretty easy, just add it (`myBindingHandler`) to the `KnockoutBindingHandlers` interface <s>right before you define your custom binding handler</s>.  **Please note that you have to do make this addition to the interface, within a `.d.ts` file as of version 1.0 (or possibly earlier).**

**bindingHandlers.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

interface KnockoutBindingHandlers {
    myBindingHandler: KnockoutBindingHandler;
}
```

**myBindingHandler.ts**

```
/// <reference path="bindingHandler.d.ts" />

ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingHandler = {...}
```

Now everything works.  This will not overwrite any existing definitions or declarations, so your definition will sit along side of `ko.bindingHandlers.text`, etc.

Just be careful, because if you do not include an actual definition of `myBindingHandler` and you reference it elsewhere, it will compile due to the definition you added to `KnockoutBindingHandlers`, but it will break at runtime because there is no implementation of `myBindingHandler`.

The documentation for adding custom bindinghandlers in knockoutjs is **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)**

### Using fn to add custom functions with TypeScript

Similarly, to add something to `ko.observable.fn`, you'd do this in typescript

```
interface KnockoutObservableFunctions  { 
    myFnExtension(args: any): returnType; 
}
```

and call it with

```
// x will be defined as a returnType automatically, but you could specify it if you like, either way
var x: returnType = ko.observable("value").myFnExtension(args);
```

Note: There are different interfaces for the `subscribable`, `observable`, `observableArray`, and `computed` types:

- `ko.subscribable.fn` ... add to `KnockoutSubscribableFunctions`
- `ko.observable.fn` ... add to `KnockoutObservableFunctions`
- `ko.observableArray.fn` ... add to `KnockoutObservableArrayFunctions`
- `ko.computed.fn` ... add to `KnockoutComputedFunctions`

The documentation for adding onto fn in knockoutjs is **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html)**

Comment: Adding the interface to the same file as the new handler didn't work for me (TS 0.9.5, VS2013), but adding it to a separate *.d.ts file did: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15876149/2381779](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15876149/2381779)

Comment: You can use myBindingHandler: KnockoutBindingHandler; as opposed to myBindingHandler: {};

Comment: Updating this answer to have info in it from this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862086/where-do-i-put-my-knockout-js-extensions-when-using-typescript-and-requirejs/15876149?noredirect=1#comment37091668_15876149

Answer (score 4):

you can simply **ignore it**,but this is **not a good practice**, by casting to `any` you are not defining the type of the property `myBindingHandler`

```
(<any>ko.bindingHandlers).myBindingHandler = { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

Another dirty way to ignore any kind of type checking:

```
let bindingHandlers: any = ko.bindingHandlers;
bindingHandlers.myHandler = {...}
```